# Calling a class constructor with an interface parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, signalr

I am currently working on a project with uses **SignalR**. The `constructor` for `Startup()` needs to be parameter-less which means to call the `ChatHub` constructor I needed to use this bit of code below.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(
        typeof(ChatHub),
        () => new ChatHub(
            new ConnectionService(null));


    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

The problem I am having is that that parameter for `ConnectionService` requires a parameter which is an `interface`

```
public partial class ConnectionService : IConnectionService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Connection> _connectionRepository;

    public ConnectionService(IRepository<Connection> connection)
    {
        this._connectionRepository = connection;
    }
}
```

Being relatively new to interfaces, I know you can't create an instance of an `interface` which means I can't just pass that into the `constructor`, so not even sure if what I want to do can even be done, any help or links to a solution are appreciated.

Comment: `null` should work for any interface :)

Comment: I did try to pass in null but when I try and use it I get an error saying object is null

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a concrete class which implements that interface. It can be a mock for testing purposes or a real implementation.

Comment: The interface is IRepository<Connection>, how would I go about creating a new class which implements this?

Comment: well... mecahnically speaking implementing an interface is implementing its contract methods, properties, events etc.. But I feel like your actual question is not that but how would you actually implement those methods, if any, properties etc. from IRepository<Connection>. This is where stackoverflow cannot help you, you need to dig deep and build the domain knowledge to be able to implement the interface. I would doubt here that anyone will copy paste the code for you .

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass a null implementation:

```
public class MyNull : ISomeInterface
{
   //You implement the ISomeInterface members with empty bodies
}
```

and then pass it in as:

```
new MyNull()
```